# iphone . ending, closing and releasing a CGContext

Tags: iphone

I have a method for creating a PDF on iPhone.

The method begins like this

```
CGContextRef pdfContext = [self createPDFContext...]
// this line creates a CGContextRef that I will use to write the page
// if not released this will leak...

// the method continues...

// at the end I have

CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
```

Xcode is complaining about the last line. If I include it, it says **Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller**

If I remove the line it says: **potential leak of an object allocated on line X** where X is the line the context was created...

If I release the context on the createPDFContext method, it crashes!

here you have the createPDF method

```
-(CGContextRef) createPDFContext:(CGRect)inMediaBox path:(CFStringRef) path
{
    CGContextRef myOutContext = NULL;
    CFURLRef url;
    CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer;

    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL,  path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

    if (url != NULL)
    {
        dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithURL (url);
        if (dataConsumer != NULL)
        {
            myOutContext = CGPDFContextCreate (dataConsumer, &inMediaBox, NULL);
            CGDataConsumerRelease (dataConsumer);
        }
        CFRelease(url);
    }

//  CGContextRelease(myOutContext);
    return myOutContext;
}
```

How to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the Cocoa memory management rules, your method createPDFContext:path: should not return an object that the caller owns.  The rules expect methods to contain "new", "copy", "alloc", and "mutableCopy" to return objects that are owned by the caller.  Your method returns a CGContextRef with a +1 retain count.  So you are correct in releasing the object returned by this method, however, the analyzer will complain about it since your naming convention goes against the rules.

You should not release the context in createPDFContext:path: as this will prevent you from ever using it.

You could fix this by renaming the method, or making it a C function.  The C function would follow the Core Foundation memory management rules which expect function names with "create" or "copy" in them to return objects that the caller owns.

Comment: I have named the method as just myPDFContext but I still see the error **Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller** on the CGContextRelease line... apparently it is impossible to solve that.

Comment: It's not impossible, you just still aren't following the naming conventions with the memory management rules.  A method called myPDFContext should return an object that the caller does not own.  Since you aren't supposed to own the return value, releasing the object appears wrong to the analyzer.  If you make your method "newPDFContext:path:" or change it to a C function CreatePDFContext( CGRect, CFStringRef ) you should get rid of the warning.

Comment: that's it. Apparently the only way to solve that is really to make it a C function. Thanks!